# Is there are way to split users permissions between

Tags: security, access, einstein-chatbot, einstein-bots

Is this possible to control which users have access to which dialogs in one Einstein Bot?
Is this possible to control which users have access to which bots?

This article https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bots_service_permissions.htm&language=en_US&type=5 is very generic and doesn't provide any granularity details information

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately current Salesforce security model doesn’t provide granularity.

The only differences in the access level are following:

View: View Set up and Configuration and Lightning User Experience permissions, View all chat bots.

[image]

Manage Bots: create and edit all chat bots.

Manage Bots Training Data: build and model intent and utterances data for all chat bots.

There is idea https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000LPPu3UAH/restrict-user-access-to-einstein-bot-instances-sharing-model-for-einsteinbots?_ga=2.214340887.1818921326.1707211542-1509603003.1707211542 on IdeaExchange for Salesforce to provide Bot granulatity security access IdeaExchange  but it is not prioritized by Salesforce Product team.